# Small values are sorted incorrectly, subset() gives wrong data in R

Tags: r, p-value, subset, gwas

I have a (gwas-)data where one column is p-value. P-values vary from $1*10^{-8}$ to $1$.

I would want to have a subset where I have only values where p-value is $5*10^{-5}$ or lower.

I have the original data in data1 and I want to put the subset in data2. data1 is read like this:

```
data1 <- read.table(paste("GwasResultsFilteredChr1.txt",sep=""), header=T, sep="\t", dec=",", as.is=T, na.strings="x")
```

When I do this with R:

`data2<-data1[data1$pval<(5*10^-5), ]`

data2 contains almost all the same rows as data1, only p-values like for example $6*10^{-5}$ and $7*10^{-7}$ are missing. P-values like $4*10^{-6}$, $2*10^{-5}$ and $0.002$ are found in data2, so clearly the code did't do what I wanted.

It seems like R somehow thinks that $0.01 < 0.1 < 1 < 1.2*10^{-2} < 1.4*10^{-7} < 3*10^{-3} < 9*10^{-4}$ etc. 
Also when I inspect the data in RStudio and sort it by p-value (Pval), it is sorted oddly (please see the screenshot)
 [image: sorted by Pval]

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I think suspicions that R doesn't know how to sort numbers properly should be way, way down your list of potential causes for bugs.

Comment: It works properly, try the reproducible example: `mtcars[mtcars$mpg < 15, ]`. You made some kind of bug in your code, but because you did not provide a reproducible example we can't tell you what was the bug. Moreover, this is a programming question, so it ia off-topic in here.

Comment: At the `R` command line, type `"1e-2" < 5e-5` and think about what the output implies.  Then investigate the data types of the fields in your data frame, as in `lapply(data1, class)`. After you're done, and have fixed the problem, sit back for a minute and contemplate the consequences of working in a programming language that automatically converts data types without warning.

Comment: The actual source of your problem is that you set `dec=","`, in `read.table`, but you can see from your screenshot that your decimal separator in the file is actually ".". Because of this, `read.table` could not parse that column as numeric and it was interpreted as character instead.

Comment: Thank you so much whuber and Chris Haug! Problem solved, sorry for being apparently off topic since this was more of a programming issue, nevertheless, I am thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It does work the way you programmed it.

```
data = data.frame(p = c(5*10^-5,5*10^-7,5*10^-8,2), i = c(1,2,3,4))
data2<-data[data$p<(5*10^-5), ]
> data2
      p i
2 5e-07 2
3 5e-08 3
```

However, you subtract a  `value` variable (that you specified before somewhere) from `data$p` and only then you do the slicing condition.

```
value = 100
data = data.frame(p = c(5*10^-5,5*10^-7,5*10^-8,2), i = c(1,2,3,4))
data2<-data[data$p-value<(5*10^-5), ]
data2
> data2
      p i
1 5e-05 1
2 5e-07 2
3 5e-08 3
4 2e+00 4
```

Is there a reason you subtract `value` from `data$p` ?

Comment: `p-value` is not a valid name in R. This may be the issue here, or the OP may simply have made a typo.

Comment: That was a typo, sorry! It should be pvalue, not p-value.

Comment: @JaakkoL can you post a small slice of the a dataframe you have?